# Invalid ModelState when moving items from one select list to another via javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a page that contains two lists, one empty, one populated with values, both identical in structure. A user can select an item from the populated list, click a button, and it will move to the empty list via jQuery. When the form is submitted, I save all the option ids into a hidden form field to be later parsed out after post. However, when I submit the page, if I have moved a value from one listbox to the other, I encounter the following error (otherwise, the page posts normally):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 
'System.String' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' failed because no type
 converter can convert between these types. at 
 System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType) at 
 System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.UnwrapPossibleArrayType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType) at 
 System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type type, CultureInfo culture) at 
 System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type type) at 
 System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.ConvertProviderResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState, String modelStateKey, ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult, Type destinationType)
```

Here is the relevant code:

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> currentUsers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> availableUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Initial Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    IEnumerable<User> availableUsers = SomeDal.GetUsers();

    var model = new ViewModel 
    {
        currentUsers = Enumerable.Empty<User>().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.id.ToString(),
            Text = x.name
        }),

        availableUsers = availableUsers.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.id.ToString(),
            Text = x.lastName
        })
    };
}
```

POST Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model) 
{
    // at this point, ModelState.IsValid is already true, so I figure the rest of this isn't necessary
}
```

The jQuery that moves items:

```
$('#swapUsers').click(function () {
    $('#availableUsers option:selected').appendTo('#currentUsers');
});
```

The ListBoxes::

```
@Html.ListBox(
         "currentUsers",
         new SelectList(Model.currentUsers, "value", "text"),
         new { @class = "listbox" }
         )

@Html.ListBox(
         "availableUsers",
         new SelectList(Model.availableUsers, "value", "text"),
         new { @class = "listbox" }
         )
```

I had thought at first it was because of my strange Enumerable.Empty call, but the error occurs even if the currentUsers IEnumerable contains data.

EDIT 1:

HTML Pre-Post

```
<select class="listbox" id="currentUsers" multiple="multiple" name="currentUsers"></select>
<select class="listbox" id="availableUsers" multiple="multiple" name="availableUsers">
    <option value="1">Test User 1</option>
    <option value="2">TestUser2</option>
</select>
```

HTML Post-Post

```
<select class="input-validation-error listbox" id="currentUsers" multiple="multiple" name="currentUsers">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Test User 1</option>
</select>
<select class="listbox" id="availableUsers" multiple="multiple" name="availableUsers">
    <option value="2">TestUser2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hmm. I think it would be helpful if you provided what the HTML for the 2 lists looks like, and a stack trace of that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the model that is getting posted to the server when the form is submitted will only include the list of selected values; You don't show/say, but it sounds like your action on submit is accepting the same ViewModel as the one you are using to display the form.  The ViewModel class has IEnumerable for each of the properties, and the error you are getting is because the ModelBinder can't convert a list of strings to an IEnumerable<User> (or IEnumerable<SelectListItem>...A bit confused about that difference; Maybe your Model coming in (or parameters) to the method has an IEnumerable<SelectListItem>?).

Really, the form submission should have a model coming in that accepts the two lists (or actually it probably only needs the currentUsers list) as a list of integers (or whatever the actual type is).

```
public ActionResult PostMethod(IEnumerable<int> currentUsers)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: (My IEnumerable<User> in model should have been IEnumerable<SelectListItem>; typo.) My submit action is taking the same ViewModel, which also contains two IEnumerable<int>s that store user ids. These are populated by parsing  hidden fields (created by jQuery upon form submission); however, my ModelState is invalid as soon as soon as I enter my submit action, so I didn't think anything that came after was relevant?

Comment: MVC is trying to populate the model for ya. I think what Chris says is accurate.

Comment: If so, then why does the form work perfectly upon a normal submit? It only throws an error when I use my little javascript function to move an item from one list to the other. That's the bit I don't entirely understand.

Comment: Actually after a little more thought, a SelectList is only going to try to submit the selected items, it won't even submit a value for unselected items in the list.  I'm guessing that your "normal submit" test doesn't include any selected items in either list - this works because the Model Binder doesn't have any data to bind to those properties.  Your JS is leaving an item selected in at least one of the lists, which then is getting posted to the server and failing to bind because the type of the property is incorrect.

Comment: You were right on the money in regards to my "normal submit" - if I select an item, I do get an exception. So I fixed the problem by having jQuery set the indexes of my list to -1, and things are good. However...I'm still confused, and was wondering if you might explain why the type is incorrect. If I understand this at all, it's because MVC is trying to bind the selected value, in this case "value" of the html option control, to a SelectListItem? Is this correct? And if so, this means I should really never pass my ViewModel to a post...but just the bits and pieces I need?

Comment: Passing a ViewModel to a post isn't necessarily a problem; The problem is that you have a property of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` with  the same name as a property that is being posted.  This can be fixed two ways - 1) Don't post anything with the same name as the select list items or 2) Use a different model for the post.  #2 is probably the more "correct" method, but it means extra code that may not be necessary (hard to say from this distance :) ).

Comment: Another thought would be to use appropriate HTML for what you are doing - eg, it sounds like you actually only need one select list, and the user can select multiple items from that list (using CTRL/SHIFT clicks) to be active.  No JS required and the system should work properly (with the properly named properties on the ViewModel).

Comment: Thanks a ton for all the advice and help. And you're right about the select list - that's what I _should_ be doing, but not what I've been told to do...it's apparently "too easy to mis-click and reset everything!" Oh well. :P

Comment: @ChrisShaffer I was having this error of passing in an item with the same name as the property type causing my model to error out! Thanks for the information.